# Problem while trying to create dynamic html

Tags: python, html, django

Why don't I get the dynamic text that I used in the views.py?

My views.py code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    context = {
        'name' : 'Amlan',
        'age' : 23,
        'nationality' : 'Indian'
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

My index.html code:

```
<h1>
    Hello {{name}}<br>You are {{age}} years old<br>You are {{nationality}}
</h1>
```

When I run the server I get:

```
Hello
You are years old
You are
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, so this could be a simple caching issue. Try restarting your server or hard-refreshing your browser.

Comment: Have tried restarting & refreshing.

Comment: Are you sure you hit the html via the view and not via a different way?

Comment: Definitely via the view.

Comment: Not sure but did you try {{ name }} with whitespaces?

Comment: Thanks. That works. Problem solved.